# List does not exist - My Alerts on this Site->Add Alerts

Tags: list, publishing-site, alert, publishing, public-website

When I try to access the URL - http://sample.url.com/sites/SiteColl/SPE/_layouts/SubChoos.aspx, it throws the below error however it is working for the other subsites

> 12/06/2011 16:08:45.59    w3wp.exe (0x1FE0)   0x16E8  SharePoint
>   Foundation    General 8kh7    High    List does not exist.  The page you
>   selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been
>   deleted by another user.  73c0b06b-ef92-4f01-b12a-f28a7e340c30
>
> 12/06/2011 16:08:45.59    w3wp.exe (0x1FE0)   0x16E8  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   List does not exist.  The page you selected contains a list that does
>   not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetViewsSchemaXml(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bFullBlown, Boolean
>   bNeedInitAllViews, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32&
>   plDefaultViewIndex, Int32& plMobileDefaultViewIndex)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetViewsSchemaXml(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bFullBlown, Boolean
>   bNeedInitAllViews, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32&
>   plDefaultViewIndex, Int32&
>   plMobileDefaultViewIndex) 73c0b06b-ef92-4f01-b12a-f28a7e340c30

Comment: What does SubChoos.aspx contain? how does it work normally?

Comment: It will allow us to select the List/Lists to enable alerts. In my case, it throws the above mentioned error while accessing the page..

Comment: Is this list being referred from some other site? Is it the same page working for all other sites?

Comment: have copied the subsite into the same site collection with a different name where it is working fine..Also, there a huge list with 5500+items, would that be an issue?

Comment: Queries on large lists get throtlled / cancelled by the API. Perhaps the code behind subchoos.aspx has trouble querying the large list because of that. You could try raising the limits in Central Admin to rule that out.

Comment: but the list which causes the issue does not have any item...do you still suggest to increase the limits.

Answer (score 1):

I think the list may be corrupt with wrong settings, etc.
Couple of things to look into -

- A). Create a new (default) view of the list - using SP Designer
- B). Delete the old (default) view of the list.

  If above still fails, then
- C.) Forcefully delete the list using
  STSADM: stsadm.exe -o forcedeletelist -url

  or POSH Script:

  1. $fooweb = Get-SPWeb fooUrl
  2. $foolist = $fooweb.Lists["fooList"]
  3. $foolist.AllowDeletion = $true
  4. $foolist.Update()
  5. $foolist.Delete()
  6. $fooweb.Dispose()
- D). Create/Copy new list.

Comment: I'm getting this error: ( $spweb.Lists["Feedback Board"] ).Delete() Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): "List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user." At line:1 char:42 + ( $spweb.Lists["Feedback Board"] ).Delete <<<< () + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: Run SPM and check the existence (& AllowDeletion property) of the list.  Check this forum post for a similar situation - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24904/how-to-delete-the-undeletable-list/24911#24911

Comment: *SPM is SharePoint Manager - http://spm.codeplex.com/

Comment: Also verify that the Site Collection Administrators matches to perform the above tasks.

Comment: 1. Verified if it is allowed to delete - > $list.AllowDeletion (Result ->True)
2. Verified if it has unique permission - > $list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments (Result -> False)
3. Verified the Lookup columns and found nothing.
4. Verified if it is related to AAM and found it is not.
5. Verified the ULS and could not find more clue(verbose)
6. Used SPM to delete however it does not show this list.
7. Used SPD however it does not show this list. 

any clue?

Comment: Is this a custom list (built up) or a list derived from a template. If the latter - can you create a new list from the same template?
I am also presuming that Site Collection Admininstration ('Full Control) and Inheritance has been verified. Can you find out which features are used by the list and if the required features turned on (e.g., Sharepoint Server Publishing Infrastructure).

Comment: Can the used features be deactivated/reactivated to help?

Comment: It is just a custom list based on the discussion board template...

Answer (score 0):

It can be an access related issue. Like, may be you dont have the proper privileges in the sub site to access the list or may be the page layout with which the page is created is not published or approved. I dont see this as a corrupted list, but a list which is not being  accessible from this particular subsite due to some privilege issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on publishing sites recently. It went away when I deactivated and reactivated the publishing feature at the site collection level.