# Unable to delete List during solution deactivate

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-foundation, sandbox-solution, feature-activation

I have two list that I need to delete when a solution is deactivated and removed. But my code doesn't seems to be working. I am trying to delete and remove the quicklinks to the lists in `FeatureDeactivating` event receiver:

```
public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            using (SPWeb webSite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
            {

                if (webSite != null)
                {
                    SPList customerList = webSite.Lists.TryGetList("SandBoxProjet - Customers");
                    if (customerList != null)
                    {
                        customerList.OnQuickLaunch = false;

                        SPListItemCollection lic = customerList.Items;
                        foreach (SPListItem item in lic)
                        {
                            item.Delete();
                        }
                        customerList.Update();
                        customerList.Delete();
                    }

                    SPList leadList = webSite.Lists.TryGetList("Sales Lead");
                    if (leadList != null)
                    {
                        leadList.OnQuickLaunch = false;

                        SPListItemCollection lic = leadList.Items;
                        foreach (SPListItem item in lic)
                        {
                            item.Delete();
                        }
                        leadList.Update();
                        leadList.Delete();
                    }

                    webSite.Update();
                }
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? I am deploying the solution as sandbox. The list seems to live even after the solution is deactivated and I am able to make modifications to the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s better to use the `Delete()` method of `SPWeb.Lists` instead of using the `Delete()` method on the `SPList` because the latter doesn't delete lists properly sometimes. Try something like:

```
SPWeb mySite= SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList myCustomList = mySite.Lists["MyCustomList"];
mySite.Lists.Delete(myCustomList.ID);
mySite.Update();
```

Comment: your code seems to do the trick! but with a slight modification: `SPWeb webSite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;` instead of `SPWeb mySite= SPContext.Current.Web;`! Why? Any reason?

Comment: SPContext.Current.Web fetches the current context from the w3wp.exe process. As the sandbox code does not run in the w3wp.exe process, it is not able to get the context. The sandbox code runs in the SPUCWorkerProcess.exe process.

Comment: code was just a sample to illustrate the usage of 'SPWeb.Lists.Delete'. Of course, SPContext works in the context of Sandbox solutions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext.current

Answer (score 1):

I just did a mini code review of your code. (I hope you don't mind). Please see if the following code works:

```
public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            //No need to use the using block here.
            //Since you are using the SPWeb object provided by the properties object,
            //you do not need to dispose it explicitly. The object will be handled by
            //the SP Framework itself.
            SPWeb webSite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb

                if (webSite != null)
                {
                    SPList customerList = webSite.Lists.TryGetList("SandBoxProjet - Customers");
                    if (customerList != null)
                    {
                        customerList.OnQuickLaunch = false;

                       //You do not need to delete every single item in the list individually.
                       //If you delete the list, each item in it will automatically get deleted.
                        customerList.Delete();
                    }

                    SPList leadList = webSite.Lists.TryGetList("Sales Lead");
                    if (leadList != null)
                    {
                        leadList.OnQuickLaunch = false;

                       //You do not need to delete every single item in the list individually.
                       //If you delete the list, each item in it will automatically get deleted.
                        leadList.Delete();
                    }

                    webSite.Update();                 
                }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the code. I agree my code is little aggresive by deleting every list item. But I already tried doing it your way and failed. Did the above code "work" for you?